# Keywords small and in French

Tags: report, keywords

How can I make my keywords small and in French?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}
\usepackage{textcase,url,titlesec}

   
%pour rendre un interligne de 1.5
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%pour les marge gauche droit haut bas
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{30mm}{30mm}{33mm}{35mm}
%pour 2 résumeé français et anglais 
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\section*{\abstractname}}{\relax}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par \vspace{.01em}\noindent{\large\bfseries \keywordsname:} #1\par}
  \def\keywordsname{Keywords}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french} 
\begin{abstract}
Résumé en français
\end{abstract}
\keywords{mot clé en français}

\selectlanguage{english} 
\begin{abstract}
Abstract in english
  \keywords{keywords in english}
  \thispagestyle{empty}

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you define both size and text yourself in these two lines:

```
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par \vspace{.01em}\noindent{\large\bfseries \keywordsname:} #1\par}
\def\keywordsname{Keywords}
```

To change the size replace `\large` by something like `\small` or whatever size works for you.

Regarding the "Keywords" name: You can locally redefine this to its french version:

```
\selectlanguage{french} 
\begin{abstract}
    Résumé en français
\end{abstract}
\def\keywordsname{Mots clés}
\keywords{mots clés en français}
```

This is of course not very elegant, but it does the trick. Any subsequent usage of `\keywords` will use the initial defintion, which in your case was the English one.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}
\usepackage{textcase,url,titlesec}


%pour rendre un interligne de 1.5
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%pour les marge gauche droit haut bas
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{30mm}{30mm}{33mm}{35mm}
%pour 2 résumeé français et anglais 
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\section*{\abstractname}}{\relax}
\newcommand{\keywords}[2]{\par \vspace{.01em}\noindent{\small\bfseries \keywordsname:} #1\par}
\def\keywordsname{Keywords}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
    
    \selectlanguage{french} 
    \begin{abstract}
        Résumé en français
    \end{abstract}
    \def\keywordsname{Mots clés}
    \keywords{mots clés en français}
    
    \selectlanguage{english} 
    \begin{abstract}
        Abstract in english
        \def\keywordsname{Keywords}
        \keywords{keywords in english}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
    \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

On a personal note: I don't really understand, why you would choose to use the `anysize` package instead of the more common `geometry` package. But that is ultimately up to you of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
\keywords{\footnotesize mot clé en français}
```

More details can be found at: [link](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/)

Comment: i tried but that don't work  :(

Comment: You could try the commands: [link](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/)

Comment: and to change the title keywords to "Mot clés" for the first abstract in the french?

Comment: @mamymamy Do you want LaTeX translates English to French by itself? I am not sure this PDF will do some help or not: [link] (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/translator/translator.pdf)

Comment: okk thank i am going to see